# extbase how to switch database underneath

Tags: extbase, typo3-7.x

We have a extension working with data of 2015. There will be the same game on 2016 with no structural change. Within the extension i would like to have a switch to change the database extbase gets the data from.

Any input how to achieve this?

thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The previously given answer on "using foreign data sources" just addresses the mapping aspect within the same database and also in terms of single-table inheritance as variant to the object-relational mapping in the domain-driven design context.

If one wants to use a different database connection or even different DBMS, there are three possibilities for the given Extbase scenario.

1. Use database abstraction layer that allows to configure additional connections

   - up to TYPO3 CMS 7, you have to install the system extension `dbal` configure
     an alternative connection and make use of that in your source code - see the
     [DBAL documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/dbal/) for details - the will be problems if using a
     different DBMS like Oracle or PostgreSQL, but it should work fine if both
     databases are based on MySQL (or MariaDB)
   - with TYPO3 CMS 8, you have the possibility to use Doctrine DBAL which allows
     to configure different connections per database-table. If the name of the
     table is the same in both databases, you need to fetch the `Connection`
     object, representing the second database individually using the
     `ConnectionPool` - see the [TYPO3 documentation on Doctrine DBAL](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/8.7/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/Index.html) for
     details
2. Use a `VIEW` with different name to the second database

   - create a `VIEW` on the infrastructure level and provide the table with
     a different table name inside the current database - this is kind of a
     work-around, but ensures that modifications to the table in your second
     database are automatically reflected with the database `VIEW`
   - make use of the mentioned TypoScript mapping of the previous post to
     connect your domain model to the database `VIEW` with the different name
3. Overload the class `Typo3DbBackend` as last resort

   - this class is responsible for actually performing database queries in the
     Extbase application context
   - there you could integrate a strategy pattern to either use the
     default implementation or to use your custom second database connection
     overloading can be defined via `ext_localconf.php` like e.g.

     ```
       $extbaseObjectContainer = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\Container\Container::class);
       $extbaseObjectContainer->registerImplementation(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Storage\BackendInterface::class, \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Storage\Typo3DbBackend::class);
     ```

Comment: Solution 1b) works fine even in TYPO3 version 10. The link to the documentation should probably being adjusted to https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility to map your models to other tables than the ones derived from the model name by convention.

Example:

```
plugin.tx_myextension {
    persistence {
        classes {
            Tx_MyExtension_Domain_Model_Person {
                mapping {
                    tableName = tt_address
                    recordType = Tx_MyExtension_Domain_Model_Person
                    columns {
                        birthday.mapOnProperty = dateOfBirth
                        street.mapOnProperty = thoroughfare
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you just want to switch the tables, you can leave out that columns mapping from the example.

More information to be found in the docs:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/4-use-foreign-data-sources.html